# Open html file in Firefox through google drive

Tags: firefox-for-android, google-drive, dropbox

I am trying to set up a portable [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/) ecosystem where I can edit the wiki regardless of where I am/what device I am using.

I would prefer to use Google Drive over DropBox (or similar) because I mainly use GDrive these days and most of the other files related to my wiki is stored on GDrive already.

I must be able to use Firefox since it is able to directly save the wiki. Chrome (or similar) prompts the user to save as or download the file, overwriting the original. This makes it a serious hassle on Android because I do not have physical access to the file in GDrive. Downloading the html, editing it and re-uploading is an unacceptable workflow.

This works fine If I use DropBox. I am able to `open with` the file, select Firefox, do my thing, and save directly back to Dropbox.

In GDrive, when I `open with` the file, I do not get an option to use Firefox, only Chrome.

Apart from using Dropbox, is there a solution to my problem? Surely opening up an html file in the browser of your choice should be a doable thing?